# Picking up where program left off after error encountered

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a program row-wise on a pandas dataframe that takes a long time to run.

The problem is, the VPN connection to the database can suddenly be lost, so I lose all my progress.

Currently, what I am doing is splitting the large dataframe into smaller chunks (500 rows at a time), and running the program on each chunk in a for loop. The result of the processing of each chunk is saved to my hard drive.

However, the chunks are still 500 rows each, so I can still lose a lot of progress when the connection is lost. Plus, I have to manually check to see where I got up to and adjust the code to pick up where the connection was lost.

What is the best way to write the code to "remember" which row the program is up to and pick up exactly where it left off once I re-establish the connection?

Current:

```
size = 500

list_of_dfs = np.split(large_df, range(size, len(large_df), size))

together_list = []

for count, chunk in enumerate(list_of_dfs):

    # Process
    chunk_processed = process_chunk(chunk)
    
    chunk_processed.to_csv(f"processed_{count}.csv")
    
    together_list.append(chunk_processed)
    
# merge lists together into one df
all_chunks_together = pd.concat(together_list)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or [byobu](https://www.byobu.org/). Edit: the previous (now deleted) comment suggested to use tmux or GNU screen, to keep alive the shell independently of the stability of the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the existing csv files to remember where to pick up:

```py
size = 500

list_of_dfs = np.split(large_df, range(size, len(large_df), size))

together_list = []

for count, chunk in enumerate(list_of_dfs):

    csv_file = f"processed_{count}.csv"

    if os.path.isfile(csv_file):
        chunk_processed = from_csv(csv_file)
    else:
        chunk_processed = process_chunk(chunk)
        chunk_processed.to_csv(csv_file)
    
    together_list.append(chunk_processed)
    
# merge lists together into one df
all_chunks_together = pd.concat(together_list)
```

You would still have to re-start your program manually every time it loses the connection. To avoid this, you could catch the exception (assuming you're getting one on connection loss) and continue like in this example:

```py
import random

random.seed(64)

l = []
while len(l) < 3:
    try:
        l = []
        for n in range(3):
            l.append(n)
            x = 1 / random.randint(0,1) # div by 0 error with 50% probability
    except:
        print("error, trying again")
        pass

print(l)
```

which yields

```
error, trying again
error, trying again
error, trying again
error, trying again
error, trying again
error, trying again
error, trying again
[0, 1, 2]
```

The downside of this approach is that you potentially re-read the csv files quite often. But assuming this is fast and you can wait, it may be fine. At least you would have no manual work to do anymore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).